# Getting location in aiogram 3

Tags: telegram, aiogram

I use aiogram 3.4.0 to build a bot, and I want to add a handler for user's location.
The following code (I deleted some other handlers and imports) raises "INFO:aiogram.event:**Update is not handled. **Duration 2 ms by bot id=xxx" when I send location to the bot.

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F, enums
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.types import Message, location 
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import ContentType


dp = Dispatcher()


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


@dp.message(ContentType.LOCATION)
async def handle_location(message: types.Message):
    print('function started')
    lat = message.location.latitude
    lon = message.location.longitude
    reply = f"latitude:  {lat}\nlongitude: {lon}"
    await message.answer(reply)`
```

I also tried @dp.message(content_type=ContentType.LOCATION) for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the handler using MagicFilters (F) and accessing the content_type there.

Like this:

```py
from aiogram import F

@dp.message(F.location)
async def handle_location(message: types.Message):
    print('function started')
    lat = message.location.latitude
    lon = message.location.longitude
    reply = f"latitude:  {lat}\nlongitude: {lon}"
    await message.answer(reply)`
```